# Where to ask about filesystem standards?

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I've recently had some questions about how to organize my files, e.g., file-hierarchy- or file-system-type questions.  I kind of feel like Stack Overflow is dedicated to code, and there may be a better site on Stack Exchange where I can ask questions like that.

I'm basically wondering things like, what is the best way to organize the files in the program I am developing, and where can I read about the different ways people organize their files.

Comment: Don't know if this is conceptual enough that it would fit on Programmers.

Comment: @BoltClock'saUnicorn I have some links and stuff.  They have this FHS: http://www.pathname.com/fhs/pub/fhs-2.3.html.  It hasn't been updated since 2004, though.  I feel like there might be a better system in place, now.  Also, I'm hoping someone can take a look at what I have and make corrections.

Comment: @Wolfpack'08: if that type of standard changed every year, it'd be useless.

Comment: @mat True man, true.  I'm creating a new software, though.  I want to account for all the current variables.  Also, my system isn't nearly as verbose.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Which computer science / programming Stack Exchange do I post in?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129598/which-computer-science-programming-stack-exchange-do-i-post-in)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Unix-like operating systems, [Unix & Linux](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) has a few questions on that topic. Look in the [directory-structure](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/directory-structure) tag. The site caters mostly to end-users and administrators, but these people can advise you, as a programmer, how you should lay out your packages so that they can be installed and managed easily.

Having read the FHS, you already know the most important things. Please [search for existing questions](https://unix.stackexchange.com/tags/directory-structure), too, as many subjects have come up already.

Not every question is suitable for Stack Exchange, of course. Examples:

- In <this environment>, should I have my program installed in `/usr` or `/usr/local`? → good
- Should I put a file with <these characteristics> in `lib` or `share`? → good
- Should I call my package `foo` or `bar` → bad, only you can know
- What's the best way to organize my files? → bad, too vague and broad

Answer (score 1):

[Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions) would be the more suitable site, however it seems that the question you have in mind wouldn't be very constructive (in the Stack Exchange sense). I'd say go ahead and ask it on Programmers, but:

1. Make it as specific as possible, tell us exactly what your project's requirements are,
2. Avoid polling for people's opinions (concentrate on technical/conceptual merits, instead of "the different ways people organize their files"), and
3. Be prepared for close and/or down votes<sup>*</sup>.

Some light reading:

- [Programmers FAQ](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq)
- [Good Subjective, Bad Subjective](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/09/good-subjective-bad-subjective/)
- [Real Questions Have Answers](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/01/real-questions-have-answers/)

<sub><sup>*</sup> Subjective questions are tough and can go either way. If you go ahead and ask, and your question gets closed, feel free to ask on [Meta Programmers](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/) on how to improve and re-open it.</sub>

Comment: Yes, I've found that project requirements are very important to the file hierarchy.  I don't think that anyone should ever be prepared for closes and down votes, though.